# What's difference between .get_rect() and pygame.Rect()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface, pygame2

I have seen `image.get_rect()` and `pygame.Rect()` being used in different programs.How do they exactly differ from each other.Don't both of these codes are used to set a rectangular boundary around a surface/image or are they different?

Answer (score 2):

`rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)` constructs an instance object of the class [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html).

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) creates a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object from a surface the size of the surface. e.g.:

```py
rect = image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
```

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the center of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).